# How can add capability of supporting handlemessage function to compound module

Tags: omnet++

Modules that contain submodules are termed compound modules, as opposed to simple modules at the lowest level of the module hierarchy. Simple modules contain the algorithms of the model. The user implements the simple modules in C++, using the simulation class library
A simple module supports handlemessage function, but a compound module doesn't support the handlemessage. An instance and most usage of compound module is AdhocHost module.
How can add capability of supporting handlemessage function to compound module?
For specially, add the handlemessage capability for AdhocHost module in the network layer.

Is it possible to use a Inet Host like e.g. the WirelessHost from inet and apply custom coding for handling the message when received? I have only seen inet tutorials using the ini and ned files.

When checking basic Tutorials without inet, like tictoc, there was the possibility to use the handleMessage function when a message has been received. Is there a similar possibility when using the WirelessHost or the AdhocHost module in the Inet?

[image: Fugure 1-The AdhocHost Compound Module]

[image: Figure 2-The AdhocHost Compound Module in https://doc.omnetpp.org › inet.node.inet.AdhocHost.html]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, you call something a "compound module" if you delegate the message processing to smaller internal modules. If you have a `handleMessage()` method and want to process the message in C++ code, that is called a simple module by definition again.

What you are asking is I guess: Can I add new behavior to INET modules that are coded in C++? And the answer is yes. You can implement your own behavior in simple modules and then you can insert those simple modules inside the node in various places. The most notable example is that you implement an application and then you can install that application inside the host, just like the applications already implemented in INET (like PingApp or UDPBasicApp etc.)

Comment: Componenets of the Ad hoc Host Compound module:
1-InterfaceTable (InterfaceTable)
2-Routing Table
3-Notification Board
4-Mobility module
5-NICs
6-Network layer
7-Transport layer protocols
8-Applications

Now to add feature handlemessage to AdhocHost, I think we need to dig the items NICs for layer 2 and Network layer for level 3. In which Inet files should we make changes?

Comment: Dear @Rudi, Your solution brought me closer to the answer, although it is more difficult to implement in practice. I wish if you have the relevant code, send it to me. Thankful